# Ajax autocomplete extender and get ID of selected item?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using the autocomplete extender to suggest names when a user types. How to get the select value after the user selects an item? I guess I can use onclientitemselected but I am not familiar on how to write this? I need to populate a textbox based on the selection in the autocompleteextender textbox. Thank you

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="27px" Width="570px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" 
    DelimiterCharacters="" Enabled="True" ServicePath="AutoComplete.asmx"  
    ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" TargetControlID="TextBox1" 
    MinimumPrefixLength="2" UseContextKey="true" ContextKey="StateDropDown" 
            CompletionListElementID="autocompleteDropDownPanel">
</asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AutoCompleteExtender` merely extends the ASP.NET `TextBox` control, so if you want to know when the text changed, then just raise the `TextChanged` event on the `TextBox` control, like this:

```
Markup:
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="27px" Width="570px" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>

Code-Behind:
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do something here with textbox value
}
```

Comment: The text changed event doesnt fire on a autocomplete selection for some reason

Comment: Karl beat me to it, so I'll add my answer below: `TextBox` has a `TextChanged` event that you can try to handle.  In my experience it hasn't been very useful, because it only fires after the user tabs out of the box (not on each character entry).  But this may work for you.

Comment: @user1342164 - `AutoPostBack` property must be true for the event to fire, see edited code above.

Comment: See my comment above--it should fire once focus leaves the textbox.  If that doesn't work for you, you have two options: JavaScript and jQuery or adding a "select" button whose event you can handle and then access the textbox's value.

Comment: Problem with this though it has a scroll bar on the extender and when you scroll it fires the text changed event

Answer (score 6):

For this you need to return the list from web service method with ID and Text

Here **"lst"** is the actual list with data from your data source.

```
List<string> items = new List<string>(count);
        for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
        {
            string str =AjaxControlToolkit.AutoCompleteExtender.CreateAutoCompleteItem(lst[i].Text,Convert.ToString(lst[i].IDValue));                
            items.Add(str);

        }
        return items.ToArray();
```

Then simple javascript

```
function GetID(source, eventArgs )
    {
        var HdnKey = eventArgs.get_value();
        document.getElementById('<%=hdnID.ClientID %>').value = HdnKey;
    }
```

and dont forget to set the attribute in auto complete extender
**OnClientItemSelected="GetID"**

Comment: This is a good answer, but see also [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/phaniraj/2007/06/19/how-to-use-a-key-value-pair-in-your-autocompleteextender-updated-again/)